# JQGrid DropDownListing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing MVC app in which I am using JQGrid. In JQGrid, I need to show CountryName but I have saved CountryID When data comes from database Country property is null.

```
public partial class 
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    }
```

In JavaScript

```
colModel: [
              { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID', sorttype: 'int' },
              { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true, inlineEditing: { keys: true }, minlength: 6 },
              { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', editable: true, inlineEditing: { keys: true } },
              { name: 'Country.Name', index: 'Country.Name', CountryID: 'name', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: citySelect() } },


            ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqgrid does not what to do with Country.Name in your column model. What I would suggest is have a new property in your partial class called CountryName as follows

```
public partial class 
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

       public string CountryName { get{return Country.Name ; }

    }
```

then update your col model as follows

```
colModel: [
              { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID', sorttype: 'int' },
              { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true, inlineEditing: { keys: true }, minlength: 6 },
              { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', editable: true, inlineEditing: { keys: true } },
              { name: 'CountryName', index: 'CountryName', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: citySelect() } },
            ],
```